# ¿Contar archivos de directorio y subdirectorios en PHP?

Tags: php, archivo

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web que básicamente se trata de ahorrar papel introduciendo allí las facturas que normalmente se imprimen en mi empresa. Quisiera tener un contador bien chulo para mostrar cuanto papel hemos ahorrado! Es decir... Básicamente **cuántos archivos de tipo PDF existen en mis directorios de almacenaje**!

Tengo las siguientes rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Por Dios! Miren cuanto he filtrado las carpetas para dividir bien la cantidad de PDF, están básicamente separados por un ID, luego el nombre de la factura y adentro están los documentos que pueden variar entre 1 y 4.

El caso es que hay muchas carpetas que adentro tienen muchas carpetas que nuevamente tienen MUCHAS CARPETAS, me estoy volviendo loco!

¿Cómo hago para saber CUANTOS archivos de tipo PDF existen en mi carpeta:

> "Uploads/live"

de manera que tenga en cuenta TODAS Las subcarpetas posibles?

He intentado esto pero no toma en cuenta las subcarpetas:

```
function contarArchivos ( $path, $extensionArchivo ) {
    $matches = glob ( $path . "*." . $extensionArchivo );
    $numDirectories = 0;
    if ( $matches ) {
       $numDirectories = count( $matches );
    }
    return $numDirectories;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo una función que probé y me funciona perfectamente en +PHP5

Esta verifica cada carpeta con archivos **.pdf** y al final devuelves el Array con el total

```
function rsearch($folder, $regPattern) {
    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
    $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
    $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $regPattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
    $fileList = array();
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
    }
    return $fileList;
}

$result = rsearch('uploads/live', '/.*.pdf/');
echo count($result);
```

Si Luego necesitas saber nombres de los archivos puedes imprimir el array

```
print_r($result);
```

Con eso puedes manejar nombre y saber cuantos archivos con "X" nombre hay.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, me funcionó de maravilla!!